# Travis CI build times out on "Collecting info for testtables..."

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I am building an Xcode project using Travis CI. Whenever Travis build the project, everything succeeds up to this message:

`Collecting info for testables...`

After that, the build times out and errors.

My `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

`language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.3
xcode_project: Project.xcodeproj
xcode_scheme: Project
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.3`

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 on the macOS Sierra beta.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re running into a [known issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3986) with xctool and Xcode 7.3, which is causing your build to fail. You could try replacing Xcode 7.3 with Xcode 7.2 in your .travis.yml, or you could replace xctool with xcodebuild using the sample script below in your .travis.yml.

```
script:
 - xcodebuild build test -project {test-project} -scheme {test-scheme} | xcpretty
```

Either option should help you get around the error.